# Referencing Previous Version of File using Filename

Tags: excel, vba, xls

I am saving workbooks with v[ ] next to them to differentiate between latest and earlier versions.

```
Workbook v1
Workbook v2
...
Workbook v365
```

Is there a way to create a dynamic formula that does the following:

1. Detects the current version (365)
2. References a specific cell (e.g. A2) in the previous version (Workbook v364)

Please let me know! Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Formula, or VBA code? What kind of workbook(s) are you talking about? `xlsx`, `xlsm`? Are all all workbooks in discussion in the same folder? Where the necessary code to be? In the one mentioned as "current version"? What does "References a cell" should mean? To make a link in a cell bringing the value of the respective cell? To use that respective cell in VBA, or what? Then, a cell **in a workbook** does not mean too much. A workbook does not have a `cell` property... Do you mean in a sheet of the previous version, named as the active one in the current one? Or, what?

Comment: When you place a question here and you really need help, it is good to check from time to time if clarification questions have been asked and answer them...

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not answer my clarification questions, the next code will assume that the current workbook is the active one, all versions exist in the same folder and the "reference cell" will be a range in the previous version workbook where from a value must be extracted and it will be found **in a sheet named as the active one in the current workbook**:

```
Sub referenceThePrevVersion()
 Dim wb As Workbook, curVers As Long, curName As String
 Dim prevVersName As String, refVal As Variant, arrCur
 Const refCell As String = "A2"

 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'it my be ThisWorkbook if you need this one where the code exists
 curName = wb.name          'the current workbook name
 arrCur = Split(curName)   'split its name by spaces and place the words in an array
 curVers = CLng(Mid(Split(arrCur(UBound(arrCur)), ".")(0), 2)) 'extract the current version
 prevVersName = VBA.replace(curName, "v" & curVers, "v" & curVers - 1) 'obtain the prev version decreasing a unit
 
 'extract the value of refCell, without opening the previous workbook:
 refVal = CellV(wb.Path & "\", prevVersName, wb.ActiveSheet.name, Range(refCell).address(, , xlR1C1))
 
 MsgBox refVal 'show the extracted value...
End Sub

Private Function CellV(fpath As String, fName As String, SheetName As String, strRange As String) As Variant
   Dim strForm As String
    strForm = "'" & fpath & "[" & fName & "]" & SheetName & "'!" & strRange
    CellV = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(strForm)
End Function
```

The extracted value is `CellV`. It now is shown in a message, you may use it as you need.

Of course, if you know the previous version name and its path, you can open it and do whatever you need with its data.

Please, send some feedback after testing the code. If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @Cla Rosie Didn't you find some time to test the above answer? If tested, didn't it return what you want?